# How to test benchmark for consumer rabbitmq by python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, performance-testing

I am a newbie in performance test for rabbiMQ.
The context:
I have the system with 10 publishers and one consumer and 2 queues ( one queue to receive the message from publishers, one queue will send message to consumer)  .we will implement the service to execute the message.

I need to test performance for the consumer to make sure it receive all messages within acceptable time.

I am using python pika . I can send message , but about performance test for consumer , I can not find any solution for this.

Is there any best practices for performance testing of consumer RabbitMQ?